# I need to include PDCurses C library into an Ada application

Tags: c, ada

I have a project which previously utilized a linux platform.  It utilized libcurses.a.  I have ported it to Windows 10 and compiled the PDCurses and created a library file. I am trying to include this library so I can get rid of the linker problems:

```
c:/gnat/2020/bin/../libexec/gcc/x86_64-pc-mingw32/9.3.1/ld.exe: C:\GNAT\2020\bin\obj\curses.o:curses.adb:(.text+0x9): undefined reference to `initscr'
c:/gnat/2020/bin/../libexec/gcc/x86_64-pc-mingw32/9.3.1/ld.exe: C:\GNAT\2020\bin\obj\curses.o:curses.adb:(.text+0xe): undefined reference to `m_erase'
```

There are more but this is just an indication.  I am using GNAT Studio from AdaCore.  I believe I need to include -lPDCurses.lib in the gnatlink but cannot see where to add it in GNAT Studio.

**EDIT:**
I have code in a specification to pragma Interface the C routines:

```
pragma INTERFACE (C, INITSCR);
pragma INTERFACE_NAME (INITSCR, "initscr");
```

Comment: I have code in a specification to pragma Interface the C routines:                                 
   pragma INTERFACE (C, INITSCR);
   pragma INTERFACE_NAME (INITSCR, "initscr");

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take the [tour] and read "[ask]". And please don't add new information as comments, nobody will care, [edit] your question instead.

Comment: Pragmata Interface and Interface_Name are Ada 83 (as is the use of "pragmata" rather than "pragmas"). If you're using GNAT, then you can use a more recent version of the language, which uses Import and Convention: pragma Import (C, Initscr, "initscr");

Answer (score 3):

If I remember correctly (I didn't use GNAT Studio by some time), in the GNAT Studio, you need to edit in menu Project->Properties (this menu name I'm not sure)->Compilation flags. There should be a text field where you can add flags to the linker.

More advanced way - you can also edit your project file in editor - this one file with extension .gpr and add there:

```
   package Linker is
      for Default_Switches ("ada") use ("-lPDCurses");
   end Linker;
```

If `-lPDCurses` of course is proper flag for PDCurses :)